# Python: Call all methods of an object with a given set of arguments

Tags: python, design-patterns

I'd like to call all methods of a python object instance with a given set of arguments, i.e. for an object like

```
class Test():
    def a(input):
        print "a: " + input
    def b(input):
        print "b: " + input
    def c(input):
        print "c: " + input
```

I would like to write a dynamic method allowing me to run

```
myMethod('test')
```

resulting in

```
a: test
b: test
c: test
```

by iterating over all test()-methods. Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Not exactly sure why you want to do this.  Normally in something like unittest you would provide an input on your class then reference it inside each test method.

Using inspect and dir.

```
from inspect import ismethod

def call_all(obj, *args, **kwargs):
    for name in dir(obj):
        attribute = getattr(obj, name)
        if ismethod(attribute):
            attribute(*args, **kwargs)

class Test():
    def a(self, input):
        print "a: " + input
    def b(self, input):
        print "b: " + input
    def c(self, input):
        print "c: " + input

call_all(Test(), 'my input')
```

Output:

```
a: my input
b: my input
c: my input
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you. I will use this kind of pattern for a rule evaluation task, not for unit- or doctesting.

Answer (score 1):

You really don't want to do this. Python ships with **two** very nice testing frameworks: see the `unittest` and `doctest` modules in the documentation.

But you could try something like:

```
def call_everything_in(an_object, *args, **kwargs):
    for item in an_object.__dict__:
        to_call = getattr(an_object, item)
        if callable(to_call): to_call(*args, **kwargs)
```